# Run Web service as windows service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I've got one silly question, as I forgot right words to explain:

How to build a web service (ASP.NET) which runs on the server non-stop, much like doing a Windows service? Is it  a background worker, or should I use some timer for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it doesn't make complete sense to have a web service do automatic continuous stuff w/o being called, do this:

1. Host the service in WCF.
2. When the service host is started, start a timer based event and do the work in a Task.
3. Have appropriate error handling.
4. This ensures your web service is also available for servicing client requests.

if #4 is not valid, then rethink web service and just have a windows service.

Comment: I was thinking about this . So it is ok to use timers in WCF ? PArticullaty I am thinking to deploy it in AppHarbor servers. Hopefully they don't have such limitations..

Comment: yes it is fine.. another approach is to have a DLL which does the heavy lifting which is used by the service & windows service. the windows service hosts the service (and the service doesn't do any timer task) and the windows service also spins up a time event with a task that leverages the DLL.. that way there is a little separation and a shift of concerns

Answer (score 1):

The web service also runs non-stop. The main difference between the two is based upon the manner in which they are accessed. Windows service does not require any user-intervention. The web service runs non-stop, and is invoked through a request via some protocol, mostly tcp/http and other protocols.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033570/what-are-the-differences-between-a-web-service-and-a-windows-service)